# Killing processes in IntelliJ without confirming

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I am working on IntelliJ 14, and running a lot of processes of my code for many tests. When I want to close them all, I right click one of the processes' tab and 'close all'. The problem is, I need to confirm disconnecting each one of the processes in the window down here.
Is there a way to close them all without needing to confirm each one of them? Couldn't find a decent solution.

[image: afasdf]

Comment: Are these processes running in debug mode?

Comment: One more question: Are you running IntelliJ on Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 7):

The processes about which you are being asked to kill are actually running Java processes.  I don't know of a way to automatically terminate these processes from within IntelliJ, but here is a one line solution you can try from a terminal:

```
kill $(ps aux | grep 'java' | awk '{print $2}')
```

Keep in mind that this will kill *any* process which has Java in its name, so be aware of this.

Comment: Nice workaround, thanks. Actually I am using Erlang at the moment, but the change needed is obvious. Wonder if there is a solution within IntelliJ

Comment: Yes it would be ideal to kill these processes from IntelliJ.  I hope another guru will answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

Run below command

```
killall /snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/181/jbr/bin/java
```

/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/181/jbr/bin/java is the path for java running intellij and can be found using below command

```
ps -eo command | grep java | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Tim [Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen) is partial and could fail.

Because `ps aux | grep 'java'` includes the `grep command`.

Therefore if `grep 'java'` command appears in `ps` list before `java` command. The `kill` command will terminate the `grep 'java'` command.

The better command is to insert the `grep` command into the `awk` command.

```
kill $(ps -eo pid,args |awk '$2 ~ "java" {print $1}')
```

You can replace `"java"` with `"intellij"` it will kill the intellij process.

This is safer, because you might have other java processes running.

But a shorter and more efficient command is `pkill`

```
pkill -af java
```